# Command 'escriptize not understood or not applicable

Tags: erlang, rebar

When I run `./rebar get-deps compile escriptize`, it fails with the following:

```
WARN:  'escriptize' command does not apply to directory /path/to/foo
Command 'escriptize' not understood or not applicable
```

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you're generating an escript package, rebar still needs the `foo.app` file. If you didn't use `./rebar create-app appid=foo` to create your "application", you'll need to create one by hand:

```
{application, foo,
 [
  {description, ""},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [
                  kernel, stdlib
                 ]},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

Note that you might need to `./rebar compile` again in order to generate the `foo.app` file before `./rebar escriptize` will generate the script correctly.